# Grok one level deep only

Tags: python, glob

I have a small python script to look for files of a particular extension within a folder,

```
for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, ext)):
    .....
```

I'm currently running this script from..say mySandbox and mySandbox has a directory DirA, mySandbox/DirA it correctly finds all files of type ext from DirA

However, I do not want it to find files from mySandbox/dummy_dir/DirA which it is currently doing..I want the glob to only work for a depth of one level. How should I specify this? Also,  if there's a better way to do this, suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to glob all the files from `/mySandbox/dummy_dir/DirA` when your python script is located at `/mySandbox`. If that is the case you can simply do this.

```
import glob
import os

PATH = "/mySandbox/DirA"
PATTERN = "*.txt"

for file_name in glob.glob(os.path.join(PATH, PATTERN)):
    print file_name
```

Comment: Sorry, I'd like it to not find files in /mySandbox/dummy_dir/DirA and only find files from /mySandbox/DirA. Only search one folder deep for files with *.txt extension. Thanks!